# How do I upgrade from Drupal 5 to 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm running Drupal 5 on my website and want to upgrade to V6. I've not got any obscure or unsupported modules running.

What do I do though? I can't seem to find any step-by-step upgrade methods.

Do I just have to overwrite all the files and then re-run the installer again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Drupal: Upgrading from 5.x to 6.x](http://drupal.org/videocasts/upgrading-to-6)

It's a video though. I have no idea what's up with all these video tutorials. Does anybody like them? Can't I get the same information in a quarter the time in text? Is the web now for illiterates only?

**Edit:** There's some text [here](http://drupal.org/upgrade/tutorial-introduction)

Comment: Video tutorials are excellent when done correctly. Like the Microsoft XNA ones, it really does make more sense when someone says "click on this part and type in this".

That's for learning a programming language though. For a mechanical thing like upgrading software a list is much better.